# postcode distances using google

Tags: r, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-visualization

I have a two lists of postcodes (in R)...one of children's addresses with their academic score and one of schools...

i would like to be able to get the closest school for each child...so presumably a calculation of distance would been needed between postcodes by converting to long and lat values?

And then I would like to be able to plot on a google map all the children per school...and see if the children who live closer to school get better grades...perhaps ploting schools a different colour to kids, and the kids having a gradient of colour according to their score?

perhaps something using the googleVis package?

so for example...

if we have the data for 3 kids and 2 schools...

```
student.data <- cbind(post.codes=c("KA12 6QE", "SW1A 0AA", "WC1X 9NT"),score=c(23,58,88))
school.postcodes <- c("SL4 6DW", "SW13 9JT")
```

(N.B. My actual data is obviously significantly larger than the one given so scalability would be useful...)

what should be done with googleVis or any other package for that matter to be able to complete the above?

Comment: You assume you have one school by postcode?

Comment: yes...each school as just one post code....that's what the `school.postcodes` object is...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would  start by something like this to  get the lat/long

**Get lat/long for each post code**

```
library(XML)
school.postcodes <- c("KA12 6QE", "SW1A 0AA", "WC1X 9NT")
ll <- lapply(school.postcodes,
    function(str){
       u <- paste('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=',str)
       doc <-  xmlTreeParse(u, useInternal=TRUE)
       lat=xpathApply(doc,'/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat',xmlValue)[[1]]
       lng=xpathApply(doc,'/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng',xmlValue)[[1]]
       c(code = str,lat = lat, lng = lng)
})
# get long/lat for the students
ll.students <- lapply(student.data$post.codes,
             function(str){
               u <- paste('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=',str)
               doc <-  xmlTreeParse(u, useInternal=TRUE)
               lat=xpathApply(doc,'/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat',xmlValue)[[1]]
               lng=xpathApply(doc,'/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng',xmlValue)[[1]]
               c(code = str,lat = lat, lng = lng)
             })

ll <- do.call(rbind,ll)
ll.students <- do.call(rbind,ll.students)

do.call(rbind,ll)
      code         lat          lng         
[1,] "KA12%206QE" "55.6188429" "-4.6766226"
[2,] "SW1A%200AA" "51.5004864" "-0.1254664"
[3,] "WC1X%209NT" "51.5287992" "-0.1181098"
```

**get the distance matrix**

```
library(RJSONIO)
dist.list <- lapply(seq(nrow(ll)),
                    function(id){
                      url <- paste("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=",
                                   ll[id,2],",",ll[id,3],
                                   "&destinations=",
                                   paste( ll.students[,2],ll.students[,3],sep=',',collapse='|'),
                                   "&sensor=false",sep ='')
                      res <- fromJSON(url)
                        hh <- sapply(res$rows[[1]]$elements,function(dest){
                          c(distance= as.numeric(dest$distance$value),
                                     duration = dest$duration$text)
                        })
                      hh <- rbind(hh,destination =  ll.students[,1])

                    })
names(dist.list) <- ll[,1]

dist.list
$`SL4 6DW`
            [,1]              [,2]      [,3]     
distance    "664698"          "36583"   "41967"  
duration    "6 hours 30 mins" "43 mins" "49 mins"
destination "1"               "2"       "3"      

$`SW13 9JT`
            [,1]              [,2]      [,3]     
distance    "682210"          "9476"    "13125"  
duration    "6 hours 39 mins" "22 mins" "27 mins"
destination "1"               "2"       "3"
```

Comment: that looks great...thanks...I know that this is probably a small thing but the distance value...what unit is that in? and secondly is there a way to get the distances between the student list and its closest school rather than the distance between the students and other students?

furthermore is there a way of incorporating it into `googleVis` to see students with their marks as one colour and schools as another?

Comment: @h.l.m the is distance in meter. The distance is given by postcode..if you give the right postcode, il will grive you the distance.

Comment: Thanks for that...any chance of getting the code for the closest school for each student? rather than the distance between students?

Comment: I'm getting an error for the first `lapply()` call Error in xpathApply(doc, "/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat",  : 
  subscript out of bounds