# two sets of locations on googlemaps

Tags: r, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-visualization

I have a two lists of locations....(via postcodes or long and lats), and would like to put two lists onto the same googlemap... but representas different colours..

It is a follow up to the original question

[postcode distances using google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241184/postcode-distances-using-google)

I.e. Is there a away to put up all the student locations and the school locations on a single google map represented as different colours?

maybe using `googleVis`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a "categories" map.  [Here is an example of a categories map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html) from [Mike Williams' Google Maps API v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/categories.htm) ported to the Google Maps API v3.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a significant amount of data it would be impractical to show them all at one time. It would be better to show only one data type eg schools and if you click on an individual marker show the nearest students within a specific radius of that school.

The answer for your last question shows you how to find the coordinates required to display on map